# Converting a java.util.Set to java.util.List in Scala

Tags: java, list, scala, set

While in a project that is a mix of Scala and Java, I need to convert a Java Set into a Java List while in the Scala portion of the code.

What are some efficient ways of doing this? I could potentially use JavaConverters to convert Java Set -> Scala Set -> Scala List -> Java List. Are there other options that would be more efficient?

Thanks

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html%23scala.collection.JavaConverters%24&sa=U&ei=IS71U-P6NIOp0QWl2oDoAg&ved=0CAsQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNElFUcaLabBzXnk1ACodkpYO8aqaQ not sufficient?

Answer (score 4):

The Java collection classes provide a constructor that takes a `Collection`, so why not just use that?

```
def js2jl[A](s: java.util.Set[A]): java.util.List[A] = new java.util.ArrayList(s)
```

Nothing Scala-specific beyond the syntax, but that's not a bad thing in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you do it just as you would in pure Java ? For example :

```
val mySet : java.util.Set[Integer] = new java.util.HashSet()
mySet.add(5)
val myList : java.util.List[Integer] = new java.util.ArrayList(mySet)
println(myList)
```

Is that what you want to do ?